# Visual studio not connecting properly with mySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, database, visual-studio

I'm using visual studio 2014 and using the windows form "drag and drop" feature to attempt to connect a single table database to a windows form. The table in question is heavily populated. The connection in the server explorer works absolutely perfectly.

However, when it comes to actually adding the data source, i get a line of irritating errors. I think there are about 3 consecutive error messages that appear?

The errors tell me as follows:

*"Some updated commands could not be generated automatically. The Database returned the following error:
Unexpected Error"*

*"Could not retrieve schema information for table or view customers"*

then in the visual studio error log, it says this:

*"Custom tool error: Failed to generate code. Object reference not set to an instance of an object."*

Obviously, these errors are somehow connected to each other. Any help would be hugely appreciated in developing my knowledge and potentially fixing this issue to display my local database.

Comment: Seems that the problem comes from user permissions, have your current user trying to accessing the DB has sufficient privileges to access schema? If it's no, use `GRANT SELECT ON information_schema.* TO [username]` (note that this command must run from root-level).

Comment: Cheers for the response buddy. May i ask how i should run this from "root level" as i have tried this command and got the error

 `Error Code: 1044. Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema' `

Comment: Before trying to reset root password, identify that root user has access to `information_schema` using `SELECT host, user, password, Grant_priv, Super_priv FROM mysql.user`, if `Grant_priv` column on root returns 'N' try running this on command line to set it back with 'Y': `UPDATE mysql.user SET Grant_priv='Y', Super_priv='Y' WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';`

Comment: I've set every single one of the permissions to Y just incase and i'm still getting the exact same errors. Thanks for the advice though. It is appriciated

Comment: If access denied error still occurs, then it means you need to do something described in this manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html (don't forget to restart MySQL instance after applying changes). If it resolves, try re-running first query given above and also check if the server running other SQL instances besides current one.

Comment: Thankyou ever so much. Nothing has worked unfortunately. If i do find a fix to this issue then i will be sure to post my response up here. Cheers